# Convert from Unix to Linux a dd with option conv=asciib

Tags: dd

I'm converting some SAS programs from a Unix server to a Linux one.

Embedded in a SAS program I have the command

```
dd if=myfile.txt ibs=1 cbs=10 count=10 skip=0 conv=asciib
```

that, on Unix, gives this output:

```
31.08.2021
10+0 records in
0+1 records out
```

That command, on Linux, gives error:

```
dd: invalid conversion: ‘asciib’
Try 'dd --help' for more information.
```

I tried with

```
dd if=myfile.txt ibs=1 cbs=10 count=10 skip=0 conv=ascii
```

but I get an output which is a bit different from the Unix one:

```
31.08.202110+0 records in
0+1 records out
10 bytes (10 B) copied, 4.8966e-05 s, 204 kB/s
```

Is it possibile to get in Linux exactly what I get in Unix?
With "exactly the same output" I intend to have a new line after the date and don't have the row

```
10 bytes (10 B) copied, 4.8966e-05 s, 204 kB/s
```

I need the exact output because afterwards it is used by the SAS program.

As required:
In Unix:
Command:

```
dd if=myfile.txt ibs=1 cbs=10 count=10 skip=0 conv=asciib 2>/dev/null | od -c
```

Result:

```
Ambiguous output redirect
```

In Linux:
Command:

```
dd if=myfile.txt ibs=1 cbs=10 count=10 skip=0 conv=ascii 2>/dev/null | od -c
```

Result:

```
0000000   3   1   .   0   8   .   2   0   2   1
0000012`enter code here`
```

Comment: Why do you need to "convert"? Unix and Linux both use ASCII, and have the same End-Of-Line character. If the file is binary, rather than text, `dd` is probably not the right tool.

Comment: @waltinator The difference is the "b" after ascii

Comment: After some research I think `dd … cbs=10 conv=ascii` should append a newline after at most 10 bytes. What Linux is it? What if you use `conv=ascii,unblock`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It works, thank you! And if I add status=noxfer I also get rid of the last line, so the result is perfect. If you would like to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: As I don't know why `conv=ascii` is not enough to get the newline in your case, I won't write an answer. Too much [voodoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo_programming) for me. I'm hoping for an educative answer from somebody else, but I won't oppose (i.e. I won't downvote) a terse answer you or I can write now. It's just I don't want to write such terse answer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski OK, I understand, don't worry. Anyway, thank you very much for solving my problem, even if with some voodoo programming :D

Comment: @Waltinator - the command in question is converting from EBCDIC to ASCII. Not the same character set. And specifically using the BSD translation tables (the 'b' at at the end of 'asciib').

Comment: @symcbean Exactly, the files are EBCDIC, received from mainframe.